# Python Simulations

Tags: python, performance, memory, data-structures, simulation

I have a general question about simulations. What are the advantages/disadvantages of each situation? Is there a preferred situation?

Situation 1: Run a simulation x times in a loop and store each result in one data structure.

Situation 2: Define a data structure of length x for each simulation parameter and run the simulation once to produce a result object of length x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mostly a question of the context your doing this in. You should decide this based of how it is easiest to work with.

If you want to use your results further, it most likely makes sense to store them under one variable with a descriptive name. This results in slightly more use of memory, but will not be noticable.

Most of the time, the datastructure you are using also provides additional utilities, like the [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) the library pandas offers.

Summary: Do what's easiest in your case. The bigger the code, the more likely a wrapping datastructure is appropriate.